# Most basic logging handler without subclassing

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

While subclassing `logging.Handler`, I can make a custom handler by doing something like:

```
import requests
import logging

class RequestsHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        res = requests.get('http://google.com')
        print (res, record)

handler = RequestsHandler()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.warning('ok!')
# <Response [200]> <LogRecord: __main__, 30, <stdin>, 1, "ok!">
```

What would be the simplest `RequestHandler` (i.e., what methods would it need?) if it was just a base class without subclassing `logging.Handler` ?

Comment: Why do you not want to subclass `logging.Handler`?

Comment: @blhsing -- to see how it works, what's going on behind the scenes, etc. etc.

Comment: Here is the source for it if you are just curious https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L849-L1036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can find out which attributes of a class is getting accessed externally by overriding the `__getattribue__` method with a wrapper function
that adds the name of the attribute being accessed to a set if the caller's class is not the same as the current class:

```
import logging
import sys

class MyHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        pass

def show_attribute(self, name):
    caller_locals = sys._getframe(1).f_locals
    if ('self' not in caller_locals or
            object.__getattribute__(caller_locals['self'], '__class__') is not
            object.__getattribute__(self, '__class__')):
        attributes.add(name)
    return original_getattribute(self, name)
attributes = set()

original_getattribute = MyHandler.__getattribute__
MyHandler.__getattribute__ = show_attribute
```

so that:

```
handler = MyHandler()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.warning('ok!')    
print(attributes)
```

outputs:

```
{'handle', 'level'}
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/UtterSoupyCollaborativesoftware

As you see from the result above, `handle` and `level` are the only attributes needed for a basic logging handler. In other words, @jirassimok is correct in that `handle` is the only method of the `Handler` class that is called externally, but one also needs to implement the `level` attribute as well since it is also directly accessed in the [`Logger.callHandlers`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1648) method:

```
if record.levelno >= hdlr.level:
```

where the `level` attribute has to be an integer, and should be `0` if records of all logging levels are to be handled.

A minimal implementation of a `Handler` class should therefore be something like:

```
class MyHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0

    def handle(self, record):
        print(record.msg)
```

so that:

```
handler = MyHandler()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.warning('ok!')
```

outputs:

```
ok!
```

Comment: thanks for this. Out of curiosity, what is the difference between the `handle` function and the `emit` function?

Comment: `handle` is a wrapper around `emit`. It calls `filter` to apply added filters and acquires/releases I/O thread lock to make logging thread-safe. Normally, you would only want to override `emit` to customize the behavior of outputting a given record, but by overriding `handle` you can have greater control over the preparation of outputting the record.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a generic way of identifying the attributes needed to implement a compatible class.

Comment: fantastic answer. This is really great, thanks for the help!

Comment: additionally, one thing I've never seen before. Could you please explain `sys._getframe(1).f_locals` and what that does?

Comment: [`sys._getframe(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) returns the caller's frame, from which you can obtain its local variables as a dict by accessing the [`f_locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) attribute of the frame object.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for `Logger.log` leads me to [`Logger.callHandlers`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1633), which calls only `handle` on the handlers. So that might be the minimum you need if you're injecting the fake handler directly into a logger instance.

If you want to really *guarantee* compatibility with the rest of the logging module, the only thing you can do is go through the module's source to figure out how it works. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html#handler-objects) is a good starting place, but that doesn't get into the internals much at all.

If you're just trying to write a dummy handler for a small use case, you could probably get away with skipping a lot of steps; try something, see where it fails, and build on that.

Otherwise, you won't have much choice but to dive into the source code (though trying things and seeing what breaks can also be a good way to find places to start reading).

A quick glance at [the class' source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L849) tells me that the only gotchas in the class are related to the module's internal management of its objects; `Handler.__init__` puts the handler into a global handler list, which the module could use in any number of places. But beyond that, the class is quite straightforward; it shouldn't be too hard to read.